# Integer to Void * ? What is the best way

Tags: c, casting, linked-list, integer, void-pointers

I've seen many topics about typecasting integers into void * but I still have trouble understanding why it works without casting them, and why solving these warnings are so time-consuming, at least the way I see it.

I tried to make this topic as small as possible but trying to explain everything, but I think explaining the steps I did, how I was trying to do it, etc.. is much easier for people to understand my issue.

I'm working with linked lists and my structure is :

```
typedef struct list_t {
    struct list_t *prev;
    void *data;
    struct list_t *next;
}list_s;
```

In the beginning, I simply set the `data` type as an integer, because I would always use integers in my program. My only problem was if I wanted to set the data value to NULL to check if there was something in my linked list (if I already used it once).

Some people would say `"just set it to zero"` but I could have a zero-value in my list, so there could be an error at some point.

I thought about `just setting a variable` such as `"has_list_been_already_used"` or something like that but I think that it would just make my code way bigger just for nothing.

My first thought after having this warning :

`warning: assignment to ‘void *’ from ‘int’ makes pointer from integer without a cast`

was: "oh I'll just cast it to void * like `(void*)my_atoi(datastring);` and that's it.

but I got another warning :

`warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size`

At this point, I didn't know what to do and didn't really find any issue to typecast this way. On the other hand, I've found another way of doing it, but I wonder if this is the right thing to do and if there is another way that doesn't lead to modifying almost all of my code and expanding it. Let me explain :

Someone said that you could just cast `integers` to `void *` this way :

```
int x = 10;
void *pointer = &x;
```

and retrieving it in the code such as :

```
int y = *((int *) pointer);
```

In my code, everywhere I would be retrieving my data from my structure, I will always have to do it this way.

Is that really the only option I got? And why just type-casting it from an `integer` to a `void*` doesn't do the job, especially if it "works well", but indeed, have warnings.

Thanks.

Comment: You could perhaps use a union { int, void *} but there is no way to distinguish NULL values, since 0 is a valid integer. The normal way to put an int in data would otherwise be data = malloc(sizeof(int)); *(int *)data = value;

Comment: Would this implementation be viable as I work with structures ? I don't see a way to just typecast the ```data``` field from my structure, I can just cast the whole ```structure->data``` "type". I'm not sure how to approach this the best way as I'm kinda new with working with linked lists and structures that way.

Comment: Why would you have "an item in the list that isn't used"? If you do, and don't have a unique value (such as `INT_MIN`) to flag it, it would be simpler to introduce another `struct` member to do the job than to use a pointer variable to store integer data.

Comment: You should be able to get rid of the `warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size` warning by casting the integer to `intptr_t` first (e.g. `(void*)(intptr_t)my_atoi(datastring)`). It's a bit of a hack because although the conversion from `void *` to `intptr_t` and back to `void *` is guaranteed to compare equal to the original `void *`, the conversion from `intptr_t` to `void *` and back to `intptr_t` is not guaranteed to compare equal to the original `intptr_t`. In practice, that is not likely to be a problem.

Comment: The whole thing is an unecessary hack and should be avoided.

Comment: You seem to misunderstand what void* really represents. It is a memory address that can point to *anything*. And yes, that includes structures too: data = (mystruct*)malloc(sizeof(mystruct)); data->mystruct_member = value;

Comment: The thing is I've got a list which always will have at least 2 integers, inside a linked list, negative or positive. I will also have a second list that is empty, but that I will be able to fill. The thing is, I wanted a way to store a number in my first list, into the empty list, but to know if it is empty or not for the next occurences, I can't just set it to 0. Because, what if the first value to store was zero? it would just re-write on top of it. Whereas if I set it to NULL, i could've checked if the value was NULL, and so I knew that my second list was empty.

Comment: As said, add another struct member, if you need to store more information. Keep it simple.

Comment: So just another struct member which holds a value, like 1 at the beginning, and the first time I go through my loop it becomes 0 and I can know if I already went in my loop ? Something like that I guess. It was my first attempt but it didn't feel like the right way, but comparing it to everything that has to be modified, and that I don't really understand, might be a better idea.

Comment: This seems like [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Kind of. But I still wanted to know if there was a better way of typecasting integers to void* because I would've made the "I entered the loop once" condition much simpler, and the rest too. But as I'm not 100% sure on how to do everything that you explained and would lead to confusion, I think I would stay on a basic value check and setting it to another value once I went in my loop. I also wanted to know why it was such a pain to typecast an integer to a void*. I understand that my integer is not a pointer, and needs to be one before setting it back to an int ( such as ```*((int*)value)``` )

Comment: Most platforms store null pointers using an "all bits zero" bit pattern, and also store the integer value 0 as an "all bits zero" representation, so converting a null pointer to an integer would produce the value 0 on most platforms. (None of that is guaranteed by the C standard - there are some obscure platforms that store null pointers as an "all bits one" representation, for example that are likely to produce a non-zero value when converted to an integer.) I'm talking about conversion of the pointer values themselves, rather than the thing they point to.

Answer (score 0):

Typecasting pointer usually doesn't do anything internally. It however tells your compiler that is is to treat the pointer as a typed pointer.

So a pointer is literally that. It points to a place in memory. And what type of object is stored at that place is not always known. You can tell your compiler that it is an integer by casting: (`int* iptr = (int*) voidptr`)
Now your compiler will read the memory location pointed to by the pointer as if it was an integer. If it was not an integer, you will get garbled data.

Now this example:

```
int x = 10;
void *pointer = &x;
```

This is ok, because you say "make a pointer (to anything) form this pointer to an int" Which is ok, because a pointer to an int always points to anything.
But if you do it the other ways you have to explicitly say that you are sure there is an int stored there, because the compiler doesn't know.

If you want, you can just make a linkedlist of integers. Then you don't even need to use pointers. Just put the integer in the struct instead of the `void*`.
The reason this linkedlist structure is written this way, is that it allows for any type of data, or data structure to be used. This is why they added stuff like templating in c++. ( But we are talking c now)

The proper c way to do it would probably be to make a macro like

```
#define declare_LL_type(type) ...
```

Which would make a custom typed linkedlist struct definition.

Comment: I originally was using ```integers``` instead of ```void *``` but as I said above, I needed a way to check if it was the first time I was going through my loop. But I guess I will avoid all of this by using an integer instead of a void* in my structure and using another value to know when I went through my loop once, such as setting a variable to 1 before entering in the loop, and if It's 1 I'll just set it to zero and it will no longer go in.